# how to remove the active class from the current element

Tags: jquery, html

I have four buttons say PASS, FAIL, BLOCKED, and ALL (by default it will be active when other button is clicked default active class will be removed). I am trying to remove the active class when all three buttons (pass, fail, blocked) are clicked and adding the active class to ALL button. But the problem is it removes active class only from the two buttons which are clicked at first and it fails to remove the active class from the latest button clicked.

**My HTML CODE:**

```
<div id="select1" class="btn-group" style="padding-top:5px;" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label id="pass" class="same btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" class="ScenarioFilter" value="pass"> Passed
    </label>
    <label id="fail" class="same btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" class="ScenarioFilter" value="fail"> Failed
    </label>
    <label id="blocked" class="same btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" class="ScenarioFilter" value="blocked"> Blocked
    </label>
    <label id="grp1" class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="checkbox" id="ScenarioDefault" value="default"> All
    </label>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#select1 input:checkbox").change(function() {
    ScenarioFilters.length = 0;
    var selected = $(this).select().val();

    $("#select1 input:checked").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != 'default') {
            ScenarioFilters.push($(this).val());
        }
    });

    $('#ScenarioDefault').removeAttr('disabled');
    if (ScenarioFilters.length > 0) {
        if (selected == 'default') {    
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $('.same').removeClass("active");
            $('.ScenarioFilter').removeAttr('checked');
        } else if (selected != 'default') {
            if (ScenarioFilters.length > 3) {
                $('.same').removeClass("active");
                $('.ScenarioFilter').removeAttr('checked');
                $(this).removeClass('active');            //Not working
                $("#grp1").addClass("active");
                $('#ScenarioDefault').attr('checked', 'checked');
            } else {
                $("#grp1").removeClass("active");
                $('#ScenarioDefault').removeAttr('checked');
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log('fkme');
        $("#grp1").addClass("active");
        $('#ScenarioDefault').attr('checked', 'checked');
        $('#ScenarioDefault').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

});
```

Comment: use toggle class

Comment: Thanks it worked..